# Retrieve result of search data from SQL server database to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to retrieve data results that are alike with what is searched for from a database and upload it in a gridview. Ok so this is what my code looks like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchVal = (string)(Session["field1"]);
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("my connection string");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM LogHelp WHERE Message LIKE '%" + searchVal + "%'", con);
    SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    var errorModel = new ErrorModel();
    List<ErrorModel> errorModelList = new List<ErrorModel>();
    // Call Read before accessing data.
    while (reader.Read())
    {

        errorModel.ErrorNo = reader["ErrorNo"].ToString();
        errorModel.Error = (DateTime)reader["Error "];
        errorModel.ErrorFix = reader["ErrorFix "].ToString();
        errorModelList.Add(errorModel);

    }

    // Call Close when done reading.
    reader.Close();

    if (errorModelList.Count > 0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        label2.Text = "No records available for your search";
    }
}
```

ok so what I want to do is if the errorModelList has values, it will then populate the values in a Gridview(Gridview1) but i don't know how to go about that.

Also the front-end is written in ASP.net. here's a bit of the code for more clarification:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <h3 style="text-align:center;"><b><u>Search Results:</u></b></h3>
    <asp:label runat="server" text="Label" ID="label2"></asp:label>
</div>
</form>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

and the errorModel used has 3 methods : ErrorNo, Error, ErrorFix which are also the names of all the columns in the database

Comment: You can use `errorModelList` as a datasource for the gridview `GridView1.DataSource = errorModelList;`

Comment: no it's not @DNKROZ, please go through the question again.

Comment: i'll try that thanks @VDWWD .

Comment: You're asking how to populate your `GridView` aren't you?

Comment: The answer from @VDWWD is the exact same as in the duplicate question that I flagged

Comment: not really, i want to populate the gridview based on a criteria from a search, if a specific condition is met @DNKROZ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152252/discussion-between-praise-hart-and-dnkroz).

Comment: Yeah you've already done that part with your SQL statement and the ` if (errorModelList.Count > 0)`. All you need to do now is bind the grid view, which is why i think it's a duplicate